# magento & Icecat live! - images not shown on category view

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I am using Magento 1.6 and the Icecat Live[link http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/icecat-live-5311.html](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/icecat-live-5311.html) plugin for descriptions and images. now i have the problem that in the category view it does not display any images but in the product view it does.

I have searched the web and found some answers, but none worked.

i tried:

edit cron settings(works fine and gives me the data imported message) 
also:

```
<schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
```

added "Used in Product Listing" to all the attributes used by icecatlive! , reindex had no effect to this.

I am out of options now, what can i do next?

thanks in advance.

p.s. sorry for the lack of tags, i cannot add them because i am fairly new here.

Answer (score 0):

Icecat Live is meant for showing icecatdata on productpages only, not in grids.
It's easier to build your own Icecat data importer than to hack Icecat Live to get ICdata on other pages using IcecatLive.

From a professional POV I don't think IcecatLive should be out there as an extension.